# Execute Makefile using Java command?

Tags: java, makefile

I'm just wandering. Is there a possibility to execute makefile.in using a Java command? Something like what you can do with Java and Ant.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean execute `make` to run the `Makefile` (easy) or interpret the contents of the `Makefile` using only Java (would be a big deal) ?

Comment: I mean java code invoke make to run Makefile. I'm creating an event handler in Java to call make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question and comments correctly, then you want to use something like [Runtime.exec(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String command = "make stuff" ; the make command you wish to run
String [] envp = { } ; if you want to set some environment variables
File dir = new File ( "/home/me/" ) ; // this is the directory where the Makefile is
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command,envp,dir);
proc.waitFor ( ) ;
```

Comment: I did read some the reference say that you can used Runtime.exec(String). The problem is, I'm not sure what should be included in the bracket. Is it the make command?

Comment: Yes, the string is the command you want to run.  You probably want a different version of the exec command that will let you specify the directory to run from.