# Execute make command from java to compile other program

Tags: java, command-line, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use javas Process.waitFor()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177711/how-to-use-javas-process-waitfor)

I have a program to upload to Arduino in my pc. I created a makefile for compiling and uploading it to arduino fio.

It works fine. 
Now I am trying to create a java program for executing that makefile but I have problems with this order:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("make");

When I execute it, program gets blocked.

Is there anything I should do to execute that order? With other orders, it works fine. make clean, make depend....

I am trying with this code I found on internet for that task:

```
public static void prueba() throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("make");
    int size;
    String s;
    int exCode = proc.waitFor();
    StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();



    while((size = proc.getInputStream().available()) != 0) {
        byte[] b = new byte[size];
        proc.getInputStream().read(b);
        s = new String(b);
        ret.append(s);
    }
    System.out.println(ret.toString());         
}
```

Comment: Maybe useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101468/execute-makefile-using-java-command

Answer (score 1):

You need to read both the input stream (stdout) and the error stream (stderr) in separate threads before calling `process.waitFor()`, in order to prevent blocking.

This article is a must-read: ["When Runtime.exec() won't"](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1) and shows you how to use `Runtime.exec` properly.

Comment: I am going to read it right now. Thank you so much.